# Binding data from parent window

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have displayed a new window from my main window. I need to Bind some data from Main.cs to a ListBox in Upload.xaml.

Best way to do this? At the moment it doesn't seem like I have access to this object as it doesn't work.

How I open the window:
Main.xaml.cs:

```
private void upload_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            //Show the upload form
            Upload uploadForm = new Upload();
            Functions.ShowDimmer(uploadForm);

            //Manage result

        }
```

The ShowDimmer Method just displays the form in the arguments, it just creates a semi transparent form behind it to dim the behind form and lay the new one on top.

And here is my XAML for Upload

```
<ListBox Width="542" Height="100" Grid.Column="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Logged, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <DockPanel Style="{StaticResource Users}">
                        <DockPanel.Background>
                            <ImageBrush ImageSource="{Binding ThumbLoc}" />
                        </DockPanel.Background>
                        <Label>
                            <Label.Content>
                                <TextBlock>
                                    <TextBlock.Text>
                                        <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0} {1}">
                                            <Binding Path="FirstName" />
                                            <Binding Path="LastName" />
                                        </MultiBinding>
                                    </TextBlock.Text>
                                </TextBlock>
                            </Label.Content>
                        </Label>
                    </DockPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

This is the List object i'm trying to bind in Main.xaml.cs

```
//Public list of users and form can access
        ObservableCollection<User> LoggedUsers = new ObservableCollection<User>();
        public ObservableCollection<User> Logged
        {
            get
            {
                return LoggedUsers;
            }
        }
```

I have tried using DataContext my Upload window, but I can't figure out how to access it:

```
public partial class Upload : Window
    {
        public Upload()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = Main.LoggedUsers;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a bad practice. But for now, try this:

```
public partial class Upload : Window {
    public Upload(YourMainWindowClassName main){
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = main.LoggedUsers; // or whatever your property name is
    }
}
```

and call it:

```
Upload uploadForm = new Upload(this);
```

Comment: What's the bad practice?

Comment: See andreask's answer for a better practice. u should know abour design patterns, etc.

Comment: @MartynBall accept the answer if it works. otherwise, let me know what happened after using the code

Comment: I will try it Sunday, sorry working and busy until then. If it works I will of course accept an answer as I always do.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you define `LoggedUsers` (and all other properties you want to bind to) in a separate Viewmodel class. Then you can:

- either set this Viewmodel as the first window's `DataContext`, pass it to the second window and set it as `DataContext` there also
- or reference the Viewmodel class in the `App.xaml`'s resources, and set both windows' `DataContext` to this exact instance by using the `StaticResource` markup extension - this will ensure that only one instance of the Viewmodel is created and used by both windows